# Need to put thread safe std::string for GNU g++ 2.95.3 on Solaris 10

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, stl, thread-safety

std::string is showing thread-unsafe behavior on Soalris 10 (compiled using GNU g++ 2.95.3).
Here's my sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void *Loop(void *) {
 while(1) {
  string *ps = new string("Hi");
  if (ps == NULL) {
   fprintf(stdout, "string creation failed\n");
}}}
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
 pthread_t thread1, thread2;
 fprintf(stdout, "creating threads\n");
 if(pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, Loop, NULL) == 0)
  fprintf(stdout, "thread 1 created\n");
 if(pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, Loop, NULL) == 0)
  fprintf(stdout, "thread 2 created\n");
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled the sourcecode (teststl.c) as:

```
g++ -c teststl.c
g++ -o teststl teststl.o -lthread
```

Platform and compiler used are:

```
Platform: Solaris 10
Compiler GNU g++ 2.95.3
```

When I run it: it shows,

```
creating threads
thread 1 created
thread 2 created
./runteststl: line 5:  1412 Bus Error               (core dumped) ./teststl
```

The following is the dump of the '`pstack core`'

```
core 'core' of 14353:   ./teststl
-----------------  lwp# 1 / thread# 1  --------------------
 00011a7c main     (1, ffbff9cc, ffbff9d4, 232f8, ff2f00c0, 0) + b4
 00011798 _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 5c
-----------------  lwp# 2 / thread# 2  --------------------
 000121ec allocate__t24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Ui (20, 20, 23104, 69, 0, 0)
 + a4
 00012220 __nw__Q2t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc
_template2b0i0_3RepUiUi (10, 10, ff000000, 0, 0, 1) + 14
 00012260 create__Q2t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_all
oc_template2b0i0_3RepUi (2, 2, ff000000, 2, 1f, fffc00) + 24
 000127a4 replace__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_allo
c_template2b0i0UiUiPCcUi (8df70, 0, ffffffff, 12a48, 2, 80808080) + 114
 00012a24 assign__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc
_template2b0i0PCcUi (8df70, 12a48, 2, 0, ff1c0200, ff1b9210) + 24
 000129e4 assign__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc
_template2b0i0PCc (8df70, 12a48, d9fd8, 129e4, ff1b03a8, ff1ba518) + 24
 00012948 __t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_templ
ate2b0i0PCc (8df70, 12a48, 12800, 0, ff1c0200, 1) + 28
 00011908 Loop__FPv (0, ff07c000, 0, 0, 118d0, 0) + 38
 ff148a20 _lwp_start (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
-----------------  lwp# 3 / thread# 3  --------------------
 000121ec allocate__t24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Ui (20, 20, 23104, 69, 0, 0)
 + a4
 00012220 __nw__Q2t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc
_template2b0i0_3RepUiUi (10, 10, ff000000, 0, 0, 1) + 14
 00012260 create__Q2t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_all
oc_template2b0i0_3RepUi (2, 2, ff000000, 2, 1, fffc00) + 24
 000127a4 replace__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_allo
c_template2b0i0UiUiPCcUi (8df60, 0, ffffffff, 12a48, 2, 80808080) + 114
 00012a24 assign__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc
_template2b0i0PCcUi (8df60, 12a48, 2, 0, ff1c0a00, ff1b9210) + 24
 000129e4 assign__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc
_template2b0i0PCc (8df60, 12a48, d9fd8, 129e4, ff1b03a8, ff1ba518) + 24
 00012948 __t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_templ
ate2b0i0PCc (8df60, 12a48, 12800, 0, ff1c0a00, 1) + 28
 00011908 Loop__FPv (0, fef7c000, 0, 0, 118d0, 0) + 38
 ff148a20 _lwp_start (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

This shows a contention problem.
Anything to do with the compilation or linking flags? Tried with suggestions from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/compile-94179/index.html but that didn't work either.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `std::string` is *not* thread-safe, but it's not the source of the core dump. Try compiling with `-g -Wall -Wextra -Werror` for a start.

Comment: GCC 2.95 has been unsupported for many, many years and there are many, many bugfixes to `std::string` in later releases. You should **really** stop using such a relic.

Comment: @YSC, read the code: it uses completely different `std::string` objects in different threads, which is meant to be safe.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: read my two assertions independently ;) (1) `std::string` is not thread-safe (it's true) ; (2) Property (1) is unrelated to the core dump. Yeah ok, it may be ambiguous.

Comment: @YSC, but `std::string` **is** thread-safe if you use distinct objects in separate threads. It's also thread-safe if you share objects between threads but only read from them, or only access distinct elements of the string.

Comment: @nos, g++ 2.95.3 does not support -pthread, it says:  unrecognized option `-pthread'

Comment: Also note that `-Wextra` is not supported by GCC 2.95, the correct option would be `-W` instead. You're unlikely to get much good advice on this site regarding GCC 2.95, because it's so old and nobody has uses it nowadays. You could try compiling with `-D_REENTRANT` to match the `-lthread` linker flag, but I don't think it will help.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: but everything is thread-safe if you use it only in one thread (except weird broken classes with static data, sure). If I said that "std::string is not thread-safe," it is to remember to the original poster that he can't, in deed, naively use a std::string object in two threads and expect everything will go smoothly. After all, remember that he presents his observations as if it were strange : "std::string is showing thread-unsafe behaviour." Though, the core dump is not the consequence of the std::string being thread-unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

The crash happens inside `std::allocator`, so I assume that is not properly thread-safe in GCC 2.95.3, but I am not going to dig out the ancient code to check.

Stop using such a relic.

Comment: For supporting legacy codebase, I am unable to upgrade the compiler version for now, any other remedy for thread-safe string or STL would help

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana that's no problem. You might not be able to upgrade them. But you won't be able to support them either. You're on your own there.

Comment: Which is the most stable version on Solaris 10 that could overcome this STL problem?

Comment: I recommend either 4.9.4 or 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Your compile/link switches seem to be incorrect. You need to add -pthreads to both compile and link steps. Without those, thread-unsafe code is used on all levels, including memory allocation.

Comment: No, that is not a valid option for 2.95.3 on Solaris, and even with modern GCC releases it has no effect on allocation (which is generally done via `malloc`, which doesn't care what GCC switches you use).

Comment: @JonathanWakely malloc itself has two versions on Solaris :) the proper one is used depending on switches. I do not remember what is the switch for gcc (especially this old), but there is a special switch. CC certainly has one.

Comment: GCC on Solaris used to support `-pthreads` (note the final 's') but I think for 2.95.3 you just need to define `_REENTRANT` when compiling, as I said in a comment above.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, alright, this is what I meant. I am pretty sure it is better to provide this switch rather than define _REENRANT. Thanks for correcting the switch.